# Problems increasing variables in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I have this code which allows me to check a hit test between a two objects

```
public function loop(e:Event):void
    {
        y +=  speed;

        if (y > stageRef.stageHeight)
        {
            setupAsteroid();

        }

        if (hitTestObject(target.hit))
        {

            q++;

            if(q == 3){

            myTextBox.text = myText;
            stage.addChild(myTextBox)
            trace(myText)


            }
            trace("Hit");
            trace(q);



            stageRef.addChild(new Explosion(stageRef, x, y));
            removeSelf();

        }
    }
```

As you can see, when 3 hit tests occur, it should print "Game Over", however I have to add this tid bit:

```
  private function removeSelf():void
    {

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);



        if (stageRef.contains(this))
        {
            stageRef.removeChild(this);
        }





    }
```

In order to remove all that is necessary, however that in turn removes my event listener, and makes q = 0 again. How can I make it to where if 3 hit tests occur, the dialogue will print out?

Comment: I'd store the value of q in an array and push to the array for every iteration in the loop

Comment: I see no code that makes `q = 0`  , or any code that shows how `q` is initialized

Comment: are you saying your `if(q == 3){` block isn't working?  Not sure what you issue is.

Comment: @Sid Smith - your code is little unreadable. So, you want to show the text AND remove the stageRef ONLY when hits are equals 3? What is stageRef - a stage reference? Why are you tracking this? Every DisplayObject has internal reference for the stage, you don't need to keep your own...

Comment: @ aadaam, I tried writing an array, and i wrote a statement saying if(myArray.length ==3), however when I push a number in and use the trace command, it just keeps adding the number to the end and not filling the whole array, so myArray.length stays at 1, instead of 3. I tried using Math.random, and it just assigns a new number to that slot in the array, but it won't actually fill the array up. @ everyone else, sorry for the messy code and lack of documentation.